# Is it possible to return both xml or json in Spring and Jersey?

Tags: java, spring, jersey

Just doing a little comparison with spring and jersey.

Curious if it is possible for a method to return both xml or json.

Maybe default to xml, but have an optional flag that will return json.

Possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mention Jersey, so I assume you are referring to a REST implementation. Jersey will automatically serialize your content as XML and JSON if your resource is properly setup. You just have to indicate a wider range of media types for your  `@Produces` annotations:

```
@GET
@Path("/somepath")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_XML})
public MyBean getData() ;
```

Where `MyBean` is an appropriately JAXB annotated POJO. With this resource endpoint definition a caller can specify what content type they want via the `Accept:` header:

```
GET http://www.example.com/somepath
Accept: text/xml
```

Comment: will it default to the first thing like json if the get request doesn't specify?

Comment: @user1361315 My experience is that it will pick the first type, but I never found any documentation to confirm the behavior.  If you have two methods each with a different Produces, it will pick the first method prior to Java 7, and a random method in Java 7.

Comment: @perception I assume that it json and html is also a valid combination then like json and XML. Correct?

Comment: @manocha_ak As a declaration of the media types that your endpoint supports there is no actual restriction. You may specify any combination of supported and even unsupported types.

Answer (score 0):

Spring offers a ContentNegotiatingViewResolver, which aims to provide this functionality.  The example from the docs:

```xml
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
  <property name="mediaTypes">
    <map>
      <entry key="atom" value="application/atom+xml"/>
      <entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
      <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
    </map>
  </property>
  <property name="viewResolvers">
    <list>
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver"/>
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
      </bean>
    </list>
  </property>
  <property name="defaultViews">
    <list>
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

describes switching between HTML and JSON, but this can easily be augmented to support XML as well, using JAXB or some other XML serializer.  For further reading:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multiple-representations

I'd post an example using XML and Jersey, but I'm not familiar with the beans for Jersey.